# Spring Data JPA, change to one attribute of Many To Many entity is wrongly being shown on all other entities that share it

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When I make changes to one attribute of an entity, it also somehow gets changed for every other entity that uses that entity. I have three entities as you can see below.

Students and courses need to have a many-to-many relationship between them and the course needs to have a one-to-many relationship with course lectures.

When I make changes to courses or course lectures that belong to a specific student by doing @Transactional `student.getCourse().get(0).setTitle("whatever")`, those changes are also reflected in other students who share the same course. I need help with this, thank you

The student class

```
public class Student {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "student_sequence",
            sequenceName = "student_sequence",
            allocationSize=1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "student_sequence")
    private Long studentId;
    private String fullName;
    @Column(name = "email_address", nullable = false)
    private String email;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "students", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Course> courses ;
    public void addCourse(Course course) {
        if (courses == null) {
            courses = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        courses.add(course);
    }
```

Course Class

```
public class Course {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "course_sequence",
            sequenceName = "course_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "course_sequence")
    private Long courseId;
    private String title;
    private double courseRating = 0;
    private LocalDateTime createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    private double completedProgress = 0; 
    @Embedded
    private CourseInformation courseInformation;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", referencedColumnName = "courseId")
    private List<CourseLecture> courseLectures;

    @ManyToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.MERGE,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "student_course_mapping",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "course_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "courseId"
            ),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "student_id",
                    referencedColumnName = "studentId"
            )
    )
    @ToString.Exclude
    private List<Student> students;
```

There is no relationship mapping in the CourseLecture class.

Answer (score 2):

This is not wrong, but just the way JPA works.
Technically it works, because they all reference the same instance as JPA guarantees to always return the same instance for a given class and id in single session.

If you don't want that you'd have to do the work either in different sessions, or you have to change your data model, so that each student has their own course. Of course this would be a strange model.

Update based on your comment:

Looks like indeed you need a different model, instead of `Student` -N-M-> `Course` you need something like `Student` -1-N-> Attendance -N-1-> `Course`, making the mapping table of your relationship into an entity and allowing it to store extra data that is specific to `Student` AND `Course`

Comment: Is there no way of making duplicates that can then later change according to students' profiles? for example when a student watched a lecture it should be marked as isCompleted=true but for other student who hasn't watched the course yet it but has the same course, the lecture should be marked isCompleted=false. right now it changes for both

Comment: As I commented on your other question and as Jens already told you: its not a many-to-many but a one-to-many relationship if each student has its own courses